# Bootstrap Modal width not adjusting to fit contents

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

After implementing a Modal dialog, I noticed it stretches very wide to wide to fit the screen but I only want it to be as wide as the contents inside it. I don't understand why this is happening when I used `width: auto;`

```js
var modalItems = document.getElementById('itemsModal');

var btnItems = document.getElementById("btn_items");

var btnCloseModalItems = document.getElementById("btn_closeItemsModal");

btnItems.onclick = function() {
  modalItems.style.display = "block";
}

btnCloseModalItems.onclick = function() {
  modalItems.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#btn_closeItemsModal {
  float: right;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.close {
  color: white;
  background-color: white;
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: auto;
}

.modal-header {
  background-color: #0099cc;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="itemsModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="btn_closeItemsModal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h3>Items</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Africa</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Antarctica</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Asia</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Eurpoe</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">North America</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Oceania</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">South America</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<button class="btn-lg btn-primary" id="btn_items">My Items</button>
```

Comment: Something like `.modal-content {max-width: -moz-max-content;}` ? Not an Answer, Just to make sure that the same style you want.

Comment: I don't want to define a specific width. I want it to be 100% on <768px devices and 'fit to contents' on >768px devices.

Comment: Tried using the class `.modal-sm`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `dispaly:table` for your `.modal-content`

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x5v7tdtx/3/)

```js
var modalItems = document.getElementById('itemsModal');

var btnItems = document.getElementById("btn_items");

var btnCloseModalItems = document.getElementById("btn_closeItemsModal");

btnItems.onclick = function() {
  modalItems.style.display = "block";
}

btnCloseModalItems.onclick = function() {
  modalItems.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#btn_closeItemsModal {
  float: right;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.close {
  color: white;
  background-color: white;
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: auto;
  display: table;
}

.modal-header {
  background-color: #0099cc;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="itemsModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="btn_closeItemsModal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h3>Items</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Africa</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Antarctica</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Asia</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Eurpoe</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">North America</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Oceania</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">South America</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<button class="btn-lg btn-primary" id="btn_items">My Items</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know that by default almost all elements(like `<div> and <p> and <h1> etc`) are having `display:block` CSS property so such all elements will take the full width of parent. So if you won't define any width for `.modal-content` and . `.modal` then due to `display:block` it will inherit the width of parent.

You should add a `max-width` constrain to your `.modal-content` to achieve this. Also you can add `margin:0 auto` to align the `.modal-content`center.